# java and tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a problem with tomcat authentication.
I want authenticate a user from a java application with nickname and password I tried to make a post to j_security_check but this does not work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please ? Is j_security_check a servlet ?

Comment: post some code, do you get any exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy's blog has a link to a file with some java form login examples, perhaps they will help you.

[Java form login examples](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/login-page-examples-jsecuritycheck.html)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do a basic authentication like mentioned above is to do the following things:

1) Inside your TOMCAT_ROOT, there is a directory "conf" which contains a file called tomcat-users.xml. Add a user and a role to this file, e.g.:

```
<tomcat-users>
  [...]
  <role rolename="authuser"/>
  <user username="user" password="password" roles="authuser"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

2) Within your application, you have to reference the defined role to restrict access to resources. To achieve this, add the following code to your WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Restrict everything</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>authuser</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

3) Restart tomcat, rebuild your application and redeploy it.